# How can I fix this misbehavior of SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to implement pull down to refresh and I am using SwipeRefreshLayout. But it's malfunctioning.

When I pull down, the SwipeRefreshLayout pulls down as it should but as soon as I remove my hand, it jumps back to the top of the first item in the RecyclerView. Halve of the loader hides behind the toolbar and the other half is visible on top the first item in recyclerview. If I pull down again, it doesn't work.

[image]

## My Layouts

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.myapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**nav_header_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
              android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
              android:gravity="bottom"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refrsh"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/pews_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="5000"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private AlertDialog internetDialog;

   private static final String GET_URLL = "https:/johnie.com/page/json";


    //Creating a list of pewss
    private List<NewsItems> mNewsItemsList;

    //Creating Views
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");

        //Initializing Views
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.pews_recycler);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refrsh);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_green_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_purple,
                android.R.color.holo_red_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_dark);


        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                refreshData();
            }
        });

        adapter = new NewsAdapter(mNewsItemsList, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



    }

    private void showDialog() {
        internetDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                ...
    }



    private void refreshData(){


        Log.d(TAG, "RefreshData called");

        //Creating a json request
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse called");

                        //calling method to parse json array
                        parseData(response);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                    }
                });

        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    }

    //This method will get data from the web api

    private void getData(){


        Log.d(TAG, "getData called");
        //Showing progress dialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(this.getResources().getString(R.string.load_pews));
        mProgressDialog.show();


        //Creating a json request
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse called");
                        //Dismissing the progress dialog
                        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                            mProgressDialog.hide();
                        }
                        /*progressDialog.dismiss();*/


                        //calling method to parse json array
                        parseData(response);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                            mProgressDialog.hide();

                            final  AlertDialog.Builder sthWrongAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            sthWrongAlert.setCancelable(false);
                            sthWrongAlert.setMessage(R.string.sth_wrongme);
                            sthWrongAlert.setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_retry, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    if (!NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(MainActivity.this)) {
                                        internetDialog.show();
                                    } else {
                                        getData();
                                    }

                                }
                            });
                            sthWrongAlert.setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                            sthWrongAlert.show();
                        }

                    }
                });

        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    }

    //This method will parse json data
    private void parseData(JSONArray array){
        Log.d(TAG, "Parsing array");


        ...
            mNewsItemsList.add(pewsItem);


        }

        adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, adapter.getItemCount());


    }


}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.example.myapp"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PostDetails"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</resources>
```

**Styles-21**

```
<resources>>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Please, what's the problem and how do I correct it?

Comment: can you post a screen shot?

Comment: What version of the Support Library are you using? Have you tried it with the latest 23.3.0?

Comment: @ianhanniballake,   no it's 23.2.1

Comment: So what happens if you use 23.3.0?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Haven't tried it.

Comment: @ank I have added the screenshot

Comment: @ianhanniballake, no difference after using 23.3.0

Comment: can you post the complete activity_main.xml code and the styles.xml. i just want to see how the toolbar was setup.

Comment: @ank I have updated the question with all my layouts.

Comment: try adding `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`
in onCreate. also can you check if you're using "NoActionBar" for your activities theme.

Comment: @ank, I did that but it didn't solve it.

Comment: ok. two more things i would like to check. can you post the codes for your styles.xml and AndroidManifest.xml. i'm thinking that maybe your activity uses a theme with an action bar that conflicts with the toolbar you defined.

Comment: @ank I have done as you requested.

Comment: styles and manifest seems to be okay. can you try using `<include layout="@layout/content_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
` in your app_bar_main.xml. this is the only difference i see between your xml and the one i did on mine. also, did you use any fragments?

Comment: @ank: It still didn't work. No, I don't use fragments and I have updated **MainActivity** Please can you take a look at it?

Comment: @X09 did you find any solution to this problem? I have the same problem. It will be helpful for me if you post your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this on the onCreated method of your MainActivity.java. Basically I just placed the referencing of the Toolbar after setContentView.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Initializing Views
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.pews_recycler);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refrsh);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_green_dark,
            android.R.color.holo_purple,
            android.R.color.holo_red_dark,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_dark);

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refreshData();
        }
    });

    adapter = new NewsAdapter(mNewsItemsList, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Also, your content_main.xml, can you try enclosing it with a FrameLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

  <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refrsh">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/pews_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="5000"/>

  </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I'm out of ideas after this. Unless you are willing to try and use Fragments which is what I usually use and it works fine so far.

Comment: It's showing now. I applied topMargin of 60dp to SwipeRefreshLayout and it's showing now. But there is another problem: After the data has been successfully fetched and parsed, the SwipeRefreshLayout remains on the screen, it doesn'r go away.

Comment: Try `mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mSwipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
` when you want to hide the swiperefreshlayout.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

private final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private AlertDialog internetDialog;

private static final String GET_URLL = "https:/johnie.com/page/json";


//Creating a list of pewss
private List<NewsItems> mNewsItemsList;

//Creating Views
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");

    //Initializing Views
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.pews_recycler);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refrsh);
    adapter = new NewsAdapter(mNewsItemsList, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    addEventSwipeRefreshLayout();
}

  private void addEventSwipeRefreshLayout() {
  mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_green_dark,
            android.R.color.holo_purple,
            android.R.color.holo_red_dark,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_dark);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

  recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(int newState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(int dx, int dy) {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0);
        }
    });

}

 @Override
public void onRefresh() {

    mSwipeLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                          @Override
                          public void run() {
                              mSwipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                              (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void run() {
                                      refreshData()
                                  }
                              }, 500);


                          }
                      }
    );
}


private void showDialog() {
    internetDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            ...
}



private void refreshData(){


    Log.d(TAG, "RefreshData called");

    //Creating a json request
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse called");

                    //calling method to parse json array
                    parseData(response);

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                }
            });

    //Creating request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

}

//This method will get data from the web api

private void getData(){


    Log.d(TAG, "getData called");
    //Showing progress dialog
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage(this.getResources().getString(R.string.load_pews));
    mProgressDialog.show();


    //Creating a json request
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse called");
                    //Dismissing the progress dialog
                    if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                        mProgressDialog.hide();
                    }
                    /*progressDialog.dismiss();*/


                    //calling method to parse json array
                    parseData(response);

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                        mProgressDialog.hide();

                        final  AlertDialog.Builder sthWrongAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        sthWrongAlert.setCancelable(false);
                        sthWrongAlert.setMessage(R.string.sth_wrongme);
                        sthWrongAlert.setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_retry, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (!NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(MainActivity.this)) {
                                    internetDialog.show();
                                } else {
                                    getData();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                        sthWrongAlert.setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                        sthWrongAlert.show();
                    }

                }
            });

    //Creating request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

}

//This method will parse json data
private void parseData(JSONArray array){
    Log.d(TAG, "Parsing array");


    ...
        mNewsItemsList.add(pewsItem);


    }

    adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, adapter.getItemCount());


}


}
```

Comment: I have updated the question with all my layouts.Please can you take a look at it?

Comment: Yes but Android Studio is complaining that "setOnScrollChangeListener  (android.view.View.OnScrollChangeListener) in View cannot be applied to  (anonymous.android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollChangeListener)

Comment: Thanks Sir but it didn't work. `setOnScrollListener` is deprecated and for `onScrollStateChanged` and `onScrolled` overrides, Android Studio is complaining that *Method does not override method from it's super class*. Please, Sir can you take a look at the code again?